# Show headers only for collections that are not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a couple of lists like this:

```
<ul>
<li class="list-header">Header</li>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

By some rules I hide and show `<li>` items so sometimes the list has visible `<li>` and sometimes it has no visible `<li>` elements at all except the one with `list-header` class, so `<li class="list-header">` is still there. I want to hide that header if there are no `<li>` visible elements in it under header. Though I want the `<ul>` still to be visible.
How do I do that?

Comment: There is no `lh` element in HTML. References: [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/index.html#elements-1), [HTML4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/index/elements.html)

Comment: @T.J. it's not the first time I've seen someone use that, why do people keep using it if it's not a part of those specifications?  Is it a part of some other specification that they're getting confused with?

Comment: Really, it's not there anymore. I modified the code accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: If the ul contains no visible elements, this element it self won't be visible. The broweser shows only an empty space.

Comment: @Keoki: I don't know, I've never seen it. It's not in [HTML 3.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32) either.

Comment: @T.J. hmm, maybe getting it confused with th, I guess :/

Comment: Hey fellow, please reread the question and let me know if you have any ideas. Thanks.

Comment: @Sergey: I've addressed the question in my answer.

Comment: A bit late in the day, but apparently `lh` was proposed for HTML 3.0, but abandoned by HTML 3.2: http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/bulletlists.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you *could* do ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/8T8t2/5/)):

```
$('ul').each(function() {
    $ul = $(this);
    $ul.find('.list-header').toggle($ul.has('li:not(.list-header):visible').length != 0);
});
```

Basically, what the above does is toggling the `.list-header` (I've wrapped it in the `.each()` in order to demo different lists) depending on whether the list `.has()` `:visible` `li` elements that are `:not(.list-header)`.

**UPDATE**
Now it works. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

<s>There is no `lh` element in HTML. References: [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/index.html#elements-1), [HTML4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/index/elements.html), [HTML 3.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32).</s> *(You've removed the `lh` from the question.)*

Instead, use an `li` with a class you style as you see fit (or if you're targeting recent-enough browses, no class required; just style `li:nth-child(1)` or `li:first-child`), and just don't hide that `li` (which will keep the `ul` visible):

```
<ul>
<li class='header'>Header</li>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

**Update**: I may have misunderstood. If you *want* to hide the header but keep the `ul` visible in some way:

A `ul` with *no* visible `li` elements will typically be invisible because it won't have any dimensions. You can override that with CSS, styling the `ul` to have a specific size ([live example](http://jsbin.com/usogik)):

CSS:

```
ul.foo {
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

HTML:

```
<p><code>ul</code> with no visible children:</p>
<ul class='foo'>
  <li style="display: none">This is hidden</li>
</ul>
<p><code>ul</code> with a visible child:</p>
<ul class='foo'>
  <li>Visible child, note that it wraps</li>
</ul>
```

And of course you can apply that via jQuery rather than with a static CSS rule:

```
$("ul.foo").css({
  width: "5em",
  height: "5em",
  backgroundColor: "#eee",
  border: "1px solid #aaa"
});
```

...so you could do that when you're hiding all of the `ul`'s elements, and undo it when showing at least one of them. After making a change:

```
var ul = $(/*...selector for the relevant list...*/);
if (ul.find('li:visible')[0]) {
    // There's at least one visible `li` child
    ul.css({/*...styles for when the list is not empty...*/});
}
else {
    // There are no visible `li` children
    ul.css({/*...styles for when the list is empty...*/});
}
```

...or better yet, add/remove a class.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `:visible` and `:not` selectors to see if there are any elements present when you change the visibility. This example toggles the visibility when clicking the elements, and hides the header if there are no elements present:

```
$('li:not(".list-header")').click(function(){
    $(this).toggle(10,function(){
       var l = $(this).parent().children('li:visible:not(".list-header")').length  
       if (l>0) $(this).parent().children('li.list-header').show();
        else $(this).parent().children('li.list-header').hide();

     });
});
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/LDG4J/4/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("ul li:not('.list-header')").each(function(index, val) {
    if ($(this).text() == '') {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
if (! ($('ul').has("li:visible:not('.list-header')").length)) {
    $('li.list-header').hide();
}
```